# Python Poetry fails to add openai-whisper due to triton installation error

Tags: python-3.x, python-poetry, openai-whisper

so im trying to use openai-whisper. i'm using poetry as my env and dependecy manager. but keep getting errors when trying to download it. the error i get is, Installing triton (2.0.0): Failed

i tried the typical poetry add and this is the error

```py
poetry add openai-whisper 
Using version ^20230314 for openai-whisper

  • Installing triton (2.0.0): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for triton (2.0.0)

  at /usr/local/Cellar/poetry/1.4.2/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:109 in choose_for
      105│ 
      106│             links.append(link)
      107│ 
      108│         if not links:
    → 109│             raise RuntimeError(f"Unable to find installation candidates for {package}")
      110│ 
      111│         # Get the best link
      112│         chosen = max(links, key=lambda link: self._sort_key(package, link))
```

Comment: What about installing this way `poetry add git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git`?

Comment: See https://github.com/openai/whisper/discussions/1048

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `triton` isnt available for combination of your platform + Python version.

When I stumble upon similar issue, I try to install the package manually via pip (`pip install triton==2.0.0`) and that usually gives me more detailed error message what went wrong.

If this wont help, please update the question with following:

- what's the version of Python in your `pyproject.toml`?
- what's your platform?

Comment: I am using a Mac with M2 and tried with python 3.10 and 3.11

Comment: @pHM did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Although it is a bit old post, but wanted to add some tips for anyone still searching for this. In our case, the developer was using python 3.10 on windows and trying to install openai-whisper 3.0 which requires triton 3.10

A seen from this [link](https://pypi.org/project/triton/2.1.0/#files), triton is not supported for windows so you have to build it yourself. You can build it from source as explained

Though this post is somewhat dated, I'd like to offer some tips for anyone still seeking information. In our situation, the developer was utilizing Python 3.10 on Windows and attempting to install openai-whisper 3.0, which necessitates Triton 3.10.

As indicated in this [link](https://pypi.org/project/triton/2.1.0/#files), Triton does not have Windows support, meaning you'll need to build it yourself. Instructions for building from source are detailed [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/triton-inference-server/user-guide/docs/customization_guide/build.html).

Comment: I am afraid it might be imprecise this- the latest triton available on pypi currently is 2.2.0. I suggest going with 2.0.0 as it seems to be more stable than 2.1.0